# Paste and Match Style - Default?

Tags: macos, copy-paste

I find that "Paste and Match Style" is more often useful than just "Paste" when I am copying text. Is there a way to make this the default behavior? The (long) keyboard shortcuts are also inconsistent between applications and difficult to remember. For example:

TextEdit - <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Chrome - <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will do the trick:

1. Go to **System Preferences / Keyboard / Keyboard Shortcuts / Applications**.
2. Click the **+** button.
3. Choose **All Applications**, from the drop-down list.
4. On the *menu title* field add **the exact name** of the menu bar item.
5. Pick your keyboard shortcut and click **Add**.

[image]

In case you overwrite the default <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> shortcut, if the application lacks the *Paste and Match Style* option, *paste* will work as usual.

Comment: In El Capitan, it is System Preferences / Keyboard / Shortcuts / App Shortcuts

Comment: I find in some circumstances that "Paste and Match Style" would fail, and paste didn't work as usual (and so I had to right-click to paste).

Comment: Yeah, I'm not convinced that Paste works normally in apps without Paste and Match Style.